# Please help me with fragments

Tags: android

I have Activity with framelayout in which fragments are loaded.
Activity to have a sidebar with a list of.

1. open fragment1
2. open fragment2
3. open fragment3

if I click on "open fragment1" fragment1 opens in which only list.
if I click on "open fragment2" or "open fragment3" opens fragment2 or fragment3 in which any of the information.

If I click on fragment1 an item in the list opens another fragment such as "someFragment" and fragment1 in backstack.

Now, if I open the side menu, and try to open or fragment2 fragment3 it opens. But when click "back" and then someFragment fragment1 overlap.

```
//open fragment1 click
                        Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1 ();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1).commit();

//open fragment2 click
                        Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2 ();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2 ).commit();
//open fragment3 click
                        EmployeessList fragment3 = new fragment3 (getString(R.string.employee_list_link));
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3 ).commit();
```

I need at the opening of the new fragment was purified backstack

in Fragment1

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment someFragment= new SomeFragment();
        fTrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, someFragment);
        fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fTrans.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before commiting a transaction which is called from side menu - add this code:

```
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(),
       FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

This will clear your current backstack.

Comment: @Sergey Balybin, post your logcat so.

Answer (score 0):

Change replace with add:

```
fTrans.add(R.id.content_frame, someFragment);
```

Comment: if I change to "add" something before you open fragment2 fragment1 first opens. ie I'm in the fragment "someFragment" click on "open fragment2" from backstack gets fragment1 then removed and in its place installed fragment2

Comment: I added the logs when creating fragment1 and they show that before calling fragment2 fragment1 again called